# Draw a polygon using draw.polygon

Tags: python, oop, draw, polygon

```
import PIL.ImageDraw as ImageDraw,PIL.Image as Image, PIL.ImageShow as ImageShow 

#that s my class Point(2D)
class Pnt(namedtuple('Pnt', 'x y')):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(Pnt, self).__init__(*args)
```

Here is the vector of the vertices(convex polygon)

```
vertix = []
vertix.append(Pnt(50, 100))
vertix.append(Pnt(100, 200))
vertix.append(Pnt(200, 200))
vertix.append(Pnt(300, 0))
vertix.append(Pnt(250, -200))
vertix.append(Pnt(100, -100))
```

Here I want to draw the polygon. The problem is it is not centered, so almost half the polynom is outside the frame.

```
im = Image.new("RGB", (600,800))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
draw.polygon(vertix, fill=230, outline=255)
im.show()
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: You need to move the polygon's vertices so they're all in positive x, positive y portion of the axis system, which usually has it origin at the upper left hand corner with the x axis pointing to the right and the y axis pointing down. To translate the vertices, construct add an x and y translation value to each point in the `vertix` list and make a new list called `vertix2`, then draw it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to center your polygon in the Image you can

1) determine the bounding box of your polygon,

2) calculate the coordinates of the center of the bounding box,

3) calculate the vector required to translate the center of the bounding box to the center of the Image rectangle,

4) create a new polygon by translating the coords of the vertices of the old poly by the vector found in step 3.